# ElasticSearch: Bool Query Scoring Issue

Tags: search, elasticsearch, filter, boolean-logic, scoring

I have a query that works probably to search across all fields for phrases separated by spaces with partial matching below. In addition, the scoring works as expected where 'Joh' has a lower score then "John' or 'John Do' has a lower score then "John Doe'

```
POST /user/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "_all": {
               "query": "John Doe",
               "operator": "or",
               "fuzziness": 2,
               "prefix_length": 1
           }
        }
    }
}
```

I am now trying to add a layer on top of this query where it returns the results above where the 'state' field MUST be 'California'. My implementation below returns the desired results but now the scoring has the name score when a match is found. For Example 'Joh' where state = 'California' returns the same score as 'John Doe' where state = 'California'. Why is the scoring no longer working properly? Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

```
GET /user/_search
{

   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match": {
               "_all": {
                  "query": "John Doe",
                  "operator": "or"
               },
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "state": "California"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }

            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are applying filter, the score will be same for all documents.
 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/function-score-filters.html#_filter_versus_query

Probably you can try using [Function Score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)

Comment: Is there a way where I can query the documents without filtering to obtain the correct score results then add a filter after concluding the query. Maybe this way the filter wont execute before the query thus giving the right results?